# Pyspark : modify a column in according to a condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe df1:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|      start_date   |value|
+-------------------+-----+
|2019-03-17 00:00:00|   35|
+-------------------+-----+
|2019-05-20 00:00:00|   40|
+-------------------+-----+
|2019-06-03 00:00:00|   10|
+-------------------+-----+
|2019-07-01 00:00:00|   12|
+-------------------+-----+
```

and another dataframe df_date :

```
+-------------------+
|       date        |
+-------------------+
|2019-02-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
|2019-04-10 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
|2019-06-14 00:00:00|   
+-------------------+
```

I did the join and now I have df with date , start_date and value but the value I want should be like this :

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|      start_date   |       date        |value|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|2019-02-01 00:00:00|2019-03-17 00:00:00|    0|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|2019-04-10 00:00:00|2019-05-20 00:00:00|   35|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|2019-06-14 00:00:00|2019-06-03 00:00:00|   85|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

everytime I should compare start_date with date if it's different I should add previous value with my value else I should keep the previous value 

I already have the new dataframe with the join in Pyspark and trying to have the new value

I used this code to get the results

```
win = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("date")
df = df.withColumn("prev_date", F.lag(F.col("start_date")).over(win))
df = df.fillna({'prev_date': 0})

df = df.withColumn("value",F.when(F.isnull( F.lag(F.col("value"), 1).over(win)),df.value).when(df.start_date != df.prev_date,df.value + F.lag(F.col("value"), 1).over(win)) .otherwise(F.lag(F.col("value"),1).over(win)))
df.show(df.count(),False)
```

The problem that the modifications is done in the same time and I need the previous value everytime

Thank you

Comment: What does the value in the df column mean? Days before start date? I suggest replacing df.value in the fifth line of your code with F.lag(F.col('value'), 1) and see if it helps.

Comment: @QuantStats the date I take it from another dataframe and I did the join ,and it gives me what I need ,...but the value I need have to change evrytime the start_date changes ...(so if start_date changes the value is the current value in the table + the previous one ,else it's the previous one )

Comment: I think I am starting to understand. Can you also show the other dataframe that you used to perform the join?

Comment: @QuantStats this dataframe +-------------------+
|       date        |
+-------------------+
|2019-02-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
|2019-04-10 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
|2019-06-14 00:00:00|   
+-------------------+

Comment: @QuantStats and the first dataframe with start_date and value

Comment: I can't see it clearly in the comment. Please write that in the main question space.

Comment: Is the expected output value in the third line really 85=35+40+10 and not 75 = 35+40. If you want to add up all values including the current row, then the values should be 35, 75, 85. If you don't want to include the current row they should be 0, 35, 75, right?

Comment: @Paul what I realy wanna do is taking the date and applying the value if the date >= the start_date ..and so one. so the value in the third line is 10+40+35  = 85 ...my final result should be for every date a value according to the start_date

Comment: @sr9419 I still think some information are missing. How does the full original data frame look like? The df you used in win = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("date"), df.withColumn("prev_date", F.lag(F.col("start_date")).over(win)). It should have at least three columns ["date","start_date","value"]. Can you print out the first few rows (don't split the columns)? Can I also see the new data frame after running your code? Please present both of them in the main question.

Comment: @QuantStats I tried Paul's code with some modifications and it works for me ,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that does what you want.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# step 1: init dataframes

cols = ["start_date", "value"]
data = [["2019-03-17 00:00:00", 35],
["2019-05-20 00:00:00", 40],
        ["2019-06-03 00:00:00", 10],
        ["2019-07-01 00:00:00", 12],
        ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

additional_dates = spark.createDataFrame([["2019-02-01 00:00:00"], ["2019-04-10 00:00:00"], ["2019-06-14 00:00:00"]], ["date"])

# step 2 calculate correct values.
# This is done by joining the df to the additinal dates and summing all values per 'date'
additional_dates = additional_dates.join(df, F.col("date") > F.col("start_date"), "left_outer").fillna(0, subset="value")
additional_dates = additional_dates.groupBy("date").agg(F.sum("value").alias("value"))
# at this point you already have 'date' + the correct value. you only need to join back the original date column

# step 3 get back the original date column
# we do this by joining on the row_number
# note that spark does not have an easy operation for adding a column from another dataframe
window_df = Window.orderBy("start_date")
window_add = Window.orderBy("date")

df = df.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(window_df))
additional_dates = additional_dates.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(window_add))

df = df.drop("value").join(additional_dates, "row_number").drop("row_number")
df.show()
```